# what's the best code structure for dependency injection in my situation?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

These codes are part of mq consumer for receive a mail sending task message, so an entry's payload map contains info about an email, like arrive address, user info. it's json format like:

```
{
    "to": "aaa@bbb.com",
    "userId": "12",
    ...
}
```

I have a listener for listening mq, like:

```
@Component
public class RecDownloadListener {

    private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Autowired
    RecDownloadListener(JavaMailSender javaMailSender){
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    }

    @Autowired
    @RabbitListener(queues = TASK)
    private void listener(RecDownloadContentBuilder builder,
                          Channel channel,
                          @Payload Map<String, String> searchParams,
                          @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long deliveryTag) {

        //I want the builder could be auto injected like @Payload or @Hearder
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

        String content = builder.getContent();
        String title = builder.getEmailTitle();
        String address = builder.getArriveAddress();

        //use above info to update mimeMessage and send it.
        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }
}
```

the last three args will be filled automatically, they are all received from rabbitmq, I wanna autowire the first `builder` like I wrote, and the `builder` like:

```
@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class TaskContentBuilder {

    private final Map<String, String> searchParams;
    private final UserDao userDao;
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine; //thymeleaf

    @Autowired
    RecDownloadContentBuilder(Map<String, String> searchParams, CpAccountDao cpAccountDao, TemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        this.searchParams = searchParams;
        this.cpAccountDao = cpAccountDao;
        this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
    }

    public String getEmailContent(){
        User user = userDao.findById(searchParams.get("userId"));
        Context context = new Context;
        // context.update(user.someInfomation())
        return templateEngine.process(template, context);
    }

    public String getEmailTitle(){...}
    public String getArriveAddress(){...}

}
```

one of `builder`'s fields `dao` is easy to inject, the listener will receive message one by one very faster, the builder is just for one message entry. should I make `(Map)searchParams` as a bean function return? Or is fine just inject only `dao` when create builder instance and set in `searchParams`?

Comment: Your question is lacking in content as well as provided code. Please enrich to provide some more code to be used to help you.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex hello, thank you for your help, I just supplemented some details, could you take a look again?